# Shutdown scheduler - Java

Tags: java, scheduler

I have the following class, which schedules the "update" method to be executed every 5 minutes. The thing is I want "update" to be executed a fixed number of times. When I use **scheduler.shutdown()** the update method does not execute anymore, but the program is still running, I suppose doing nothing.

How can I stop it completely?

```
static Runnable update = new Runnable() {        
    @Override
    public void run() {

        if (count >= MAX_UPDATES) {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } else {
            //Do something
            count++;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(update, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: `System.exit(int exitCode);`

Comment: @StormeHawke ^ works. Kinda obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Here, I'll add it as an answer

Comment: Though System.exit() works I am surprised that what else running to keep your program running. I would make sure no thread/memory leaks due to this before simply assuming everything good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `System.exit(int exitCode);`

Note that if you do so, the jvm will terminate immediately.  Also this is the only situation where a `finally{}` block will NOT execute.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use [shutdownNow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow%28%29) method, this should `Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks and halts the processing of waiting tasks` according to the docs.

Comment: Shutdown does almost the same, but waits for executing tasks to finish. The point is "update" does not get executed anymore, but the program doesn't terminate

Comment: @Alex I think this is the correct way, your application possible doesn't terminate because the `Executors` thread didn't terminate, which `shutdownNow` does